# Parallel programming using Java thread

Tags: java

I have 2 classes

```
public class Account {

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getCompany() {
        return company;
    }
    public void setCompany(String company) {
        this.company = company;
    }
    public String name;
    public String company;
}



public class Estimates {

    public String market;
    public String getMarket() {
        return market;
    }
    public void setMarket(String market) {
        this.market = market;
    }
    public Account getAccount() {
        return account;
    }
    public void setAccount(Account account) {
        this.account = account;
    }
    public Account account;
}
```

Estimates objects gets created 1000 times , I have to iterate Estimates objects in a For Each loop and Perform some some calculation who's results are stored in Account object and set back to estimate object.

```
for(Estimates estimate : estimateList)
{
// account is a result of some calculation
estimate.setAccount(account);
}
```

This happens in a sequential manner and creates a performs lag , can this be converted to parallel execution using java thread?
Each account object calls a method that perform some calculation.

Comment: How have you reached the conclusion that this causes a performance lag?  1000 times is nothing.  The calculation might be expensive, but the rest probably shouldn't be.

Comment: Because in UI , it was waiting for 20 seconds for the page to load and this loop is causing the delay , 1000 is just an example , in reality it can even be more. Response of this loop is the input for UI

Comment: yes, it can be, but what you need to take into consideration, and whether that's going to help at all, depends on lots of details that you didn't specify. If you're interested in trying it, this doesn't feel like an SO kind of question: Any arbitrary tutorial about multicore or fork/join will cover these topics.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/thread-pool-java-and-guava

Comment: Try java Stream APIs.
`estimateList.parallelStream().foreach(Estimates.setAccount(account))

Comment: @G10 you do realize that the estimate loop is what is done in parallel not the entire operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This happens in a sequential manner and creates a performs lag , can this be converted to parallel execution using java thread?

Yes can improve the performance this way.

Possible solution with **Java Thread**:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Estimates> estimateList = ... // Set the list of Estimates objects here

        int numThreads = 3; // set the number of threads you want to use
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);

        try {
            int chunkSize = estimateList.size() / numThreads;

            for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
                int startIndex = i * chunkSize;
                int endIndex = (i == numThreads - 1) ? estimateList.size() : (startIndex + chunkSize);
                List<Estimates> chunk = estimateList.subList(startIndex, endIndex);

                executorService.execute(() -> {
                    for (Estimates estimate : chunk) {
                        Account account = performCalculations(estimate);
                        estimate.setAccount(account);
                    }
                });
            }
        } finally {
            executorService.shutdown();
            try {
                executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // Put the handling of a thread interruption here
            }
        }
    }

    private static Account performCalculations(Estimates estimate) {
        // do your calculations and return the Account object here
        return new Account();
    }
}
```

Furthermore I suggest other option.

You can use **java Stream API.**

```
       List<Estimates> updatedEstimates = estimateList.parallelStream()
            .map(estimate -> {
                Account account = performCalculations(estimate);
                estimate.setAccount(account);
                return estimate;
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This code does not capture Exceptions